# What is a cone of a lattice?

Tags: representation-theory, terminology, lattice-orders

I'm reading Fulton Harris group representation theory.
I encountered this:

"The virtual characters of $G$ form a lattice $\Lambda \cong \mathbb Z^{\mathfrak c} \in \mathbb C_{\text{class}}(G)$, in which the
actual characters sit as a cone $\Lambda_0 \cong \mathbb N^{\mathfrak c} \subset \mathbb Z^{\mathfrak c}$"

I've only ever taken an introduction to Lattice theory, when I took abstract algebra, and I don't think I've encountered the term "cone", and when searching for what a cone of a lattice is, the results are confusing and I can't make sense of them.

Comment: In this context, it means that it is stable by sums.

Comment: @CaptainLama I'm sorry, English isn't my first language, does stable by sums mean closed under addition?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.